# affected/package: database/sql "Deficiency in the code"

Tags: go, plsql

go version: go 1.19

my problem is with the database/sql package. I have plsql code available in service. values are sent to the service via map. but the number is not limited,

I need to send to db.exec() via sql.Named, I checked with loop and with interface, it didn't work.

Please help me.

my codes are:

in the controller

```
const begin = "
jsonData.Put('stateid', :stateid);
"
array_for_param := map[string]string{
    "stateid": "a",
}
temp, err := services.Perform(c, begin, array_for_param, i_User_Id)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

service code:

```
var params []interface{}
for key, value := range array_for_param {
    params = append(params, sql.Named(key, value))
}
if _, err := db.Exec(declare+begin+end,
    sql.Named("i_User_Id", i_User_Id),
    params...,
); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The main problem I have is that I need to send the sql.Named code using a for, which is an unknown number

I did that too

```
if _, err := db.Exec(declare+begin+end,
sql.Named("i_User_Id", i_User_Id),
for key, value := range array_for_param {
    return sql.Named(key, value)
}
); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Can you better detail the question? Maybe provide the model/table you're using and arrange the provided code in a better way. A suggestion can be to use an ORM like gorm for CREATE, UPDATE, and DELETE commands.